# Como que eu mudo a cor da borda da tag input quando selecionada

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como que eu mudo a cor da borda do checkbox quando, por exemplo a opcao 1 é selecionada?

Dado o meu código html:

```
<div class="opcao-de-entrega">

   <p class="menu-opcoes-titulo">
             Opções de entrega
    </p>
    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label><input type="checkbox" value="1">Sedex 1</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label><input type="checkbox" value="2">Economica 2</label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Retirar na Guiatel 3</label>
                      </div>

                    </div>
```

No script quero que tipo somente se eu selecionar o primeiro input este fique selecionado e a borda apareça, sou bem noob, tipo tentei como nessa tela tem 3 input, fazer o `if(input["0"].checked)` ai este ficasse vermelho/azul etc, mas eu quero que tipo eu marquei o input 1, por exemplo, ai eu desmarco, a borda suma também. help?

```
 $('.checkbox label')



$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  //var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
        //this.style('border', '1px solid red');
        console.log("aqui");
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').parent().css('border', '1px solid red');

    }
});
```

Comment: Tatah vc consegue fazer isso perfeitamente apenas com CSS, não precisa de JA ou jQuery, se tiver interesse respondo com um exemplo pra vc

Comment: @hugocsl como? porque tipo são 3 input vc usaria :active ?

Comment: Não, se for input obrigatório é melhor pq vc pode usar valid e invalid, se for um input padrão vc usa focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma alternativa simples é usar o método **toggleClass** nos eventos **focus** e **blur**.

```js
$('input.colorir').bind('focus blur',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('input_colorido');
});
```

```css
input{
  outline: none;
}

.input_colorido{
  background-color: #FFFF99;
  border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="colorir" type="text" value="AbCde" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($("#IdDoCheck").is(':checked')) {
            $("#IdDoCheck").css({ "border-color": "#F00", "padding": "1px" });


        } else {
            $("#IdDoCheck").css({ "border-color": "blue", "padding": "1px" });

        }
```

Comment: vou tentar aqui, obrigada

Comment: coloquei o "else"

Comment: Se a resposta serviu, marque ela ! Boa sorte

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso apenas com CSS, quando o input for selecionado você altera a cor, a propriedade CSS para isso seria o :focus, portanto o código para realizar tal ação ficaria assim:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:focus {
  border-color: red; 
}
```

Para saber mais sobre pseudo-classes em CSS, só acessar esses links: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp (EN)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.htm (EN)
https://medium.com/@88181514gabriel/seletores-css-pseudo-classes-c9d2125480d8 (PT-BR)